# Laravel Eloquent query using where

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have two models. A status and a SaleDetails.

```
Status
------ 
  id
 name
 slug
```

I didn't define any relationship from Status to SaleDetails.

```
SaleDetails
-----------  
  id
  id_statuses //connects it to the status table
  id_products
  price
  qty
```

---

in the Model:

```
  public function status(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Status', 'id_statuses', 'id');
}
```

So what I am trying to do here is get all orders that whose status match a certain slug.
E.g `dd($this->sale_details->where('status.slug', 'pending')`

With what I have using this:

`$orders = $this->sale_details->with('product', 'status')->today()->get();`

I should be able to filter them based on the status slugs in the frontend, but I want to just do it straight from here.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `whereHas()` it allows you to specify additional filters for the related model to check.

To apply the where condition you can use `whereHas()` like,

```
$status = "pending";

$this->sale_details->whereHas('status', function($q) use ($status){
   $q->where('slug', $status);
})->get();
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! What does the closure do in this case? what part of the docs can I go to read more about this?

Comment: You can just read this doc. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#introduction.

Answer (score -2):

i think, better than using  **query builder** if you want fast proccess